# Datapower adds characters outside soap envelope. What are they?

Tags: ibm-datapower

First off, I'm a total newbie and am way over my head. I have googled my brains out and cant get what seems like a super easy question answered. My company just started sending requests via datapower and although we havent changed other things we have a partner who is receiving a constant 3 characters above the soap envelope and a 0 below it. Exactly like the example below. I cant find for the life of me what these numbers are supposed to represent and why we are all of a sudden sending them because of a switch to datapower. Any insight would be much appreciated.  TIA.

In this example the 191 and 0 are the problem.

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 16 Feb 2008 00:30:34 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Transport-Caps-Negotiation-Flags: 0,0,0,0,0
Content-Type: text/xml

191

```
<soap:Envelope/>
```

0

Comment: Sorry...the issue is in the response received by partner. We do not see the 191 and 0 in our response.

Answer (score 1):

I see `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` in the headers, so the `191` and `0` are chunk lengths.  Read about it [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) and [in RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.6.1).

If the receiver does not understand chunked encoding (?), you might have to disable it somewhere in the SOAP handler or IIS.